# Firefox "Open links in apps" blacklist?

Tags: youtube, firefox-for-android

I'm generally OK with urls opening dedicated apps, but there's 2 exceptions:

```
youtu.be
youtube.com
```

i don't want these 2 urls to open in the dedicated youtube app. is there some way to blacklist these 2 urls from "Open links in apps" ?

in case you wonder, i have 2 issues with the YouTube app,

#1: there's lots of ads, and because i'm banned from YouTube (since 2018, but seems its a lifetime ban) i am not allowed to buy Youtube Premium even if i wanted to. Firefox supports uBlock Origin, the youtube app does not.

#2: the YouTube app does not support playing in the background/pure audio, while Firefox does.

Comment: Go to **App info** -> **Open by default** -> **Open supported links** and select **Ask every time**. // Another option is to uninstall or disable YouTube app.

Comment: @IrfanLatif there is no `Open by default` in App Info for both FireFox and Youtube, so "App info" where? also the uninstall button for YouTube is disabled (i'm sure it can be uninstalled via rooting/adb, but cannot uninstall it the normal way at least) - the phone is a not-rooted Samsung S22U with Android 12 if that's relevant